# Combobox date format

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in an Excel sheet where I want all the data between a date range.

I created a userform with two comboboxes (one for start date & another for end date) to select the date range.

When I select the date it displays in number format. e.g. 41118 for date 28-07-2012.

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ComboBox1.Value = Format(ComboBox1.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
End Sub
```

The problem is solved but it is slow and taking 10-15 seconds to select the date.

Comment: even dates are repeating so I want to remove the same date which is appearing more than one. i.e if five row has the same date 01-01-2016 then the date 01-01-2016 is appearing in the drop down menu for five times but i need it only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the Value of the ComboBox in it's change event will trigger the event again, which will kind of be like a loop. Try disabling the Events before you change the Value and enable them afterwards:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Application.EnableEvents = False
ComboBox1.Value = Format(ComboBox1.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I did the same as you suggested & disable the events but the problem is not solved. Pls guide me what can I do. & what can I do for second issue which is repeating the dates in combo box.

Comment: I did as you suggested & tried above code but the problem is not solved. I don't  what is cause to make is slow & how to control that. 
And also pls guide me for another issue of repeating the same dates in combo box.

Comment: Pls someone can help me to find out the issue. disabling events is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code allows only date values in the format "dd.mm.yyyy" to be added into the textbox (change that for combobox). Dates must be larger than 01.01.2000 and smaller than 31.12.2099 and a message is displayed to alert if the date entered is in the future:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim ldm As Integer
Dim Reply As Long
Application.EnableEvents = False
If InStr(1, Join(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "."), "|"), Right(TextBox1.Text, 1)) = 0 Then _
TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, Len(TextBox1.Text) - 1)
If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 1 Then
    If TextBox1.Text > 3 Then
        TextBox1.Text = "0" & TextBox1.Text
    End If
ElseIf Len(TextBox1.Text) = 2 Then
    If Mid(TextBox1.Text, 2, 1) = "." Then
        TextBox1.Text = "0" & Left(TextBox1.Text, 1) & "."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text < 31 Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "."
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "31."
    End If
ElseIf Len(TextBox1.Text) = 4 Then
    If Right(TextBox1.Text, 1) > 1 Then
        TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 3) & "0" & Right(TextBox1.Text, 1)
    End If
ElseIf Len(TextBox1.Text) = 5 Then
    If Right(TextBox1.Text, 1) = "." Then
        If Mid(TextBox1.Text, 4, 1) = 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 4)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 3) & "0" & Mid(TextBox1.Text, 4, 1) & "."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    If Right(TextBox1.Text, 2) < 13 Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "."
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 3) & "12."
    End If
ElseIf Len(TextBox1.Text) = 7 Then
    If Right(TextBox1.Text, 1) <> "2" Then
        TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 6) & "2"
    End If
ElseIf Len(TextBox1.Text) = 8 Then
    If InStr(1, Join(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), "|"), Right(TextBox1.Text, 1)) = 0 Then _
    TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, Len(TextBox1.Text) - 1)
    If Right(TextBox1.Text, 1) > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 7) & "0"
    End If
ElseIf Len(TextBox1.Text) = 9 Then
    If InStr(1, Join(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), "|"), Right(TextBox1.Text, 1)) = 0 Then _
    TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, Len(TextBox1.Text) - 1)
ElseIf Len(TextBox1.Text) = 10 Then
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) = False Then TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 8)
    ldm = Format(DateSerial((Right(TextBox1.Text, 4)), (Mid(TextBox1.Text, 4, 2)) + 1, 0), "d")
    If Left(TextBox1.Text, 2) > ldm Then TextBox1.Text = ldm & Right(TextBox1.Text, 8)
    If DateSerial(Right(TextBox1.Text, 4), Mid(TextBox1.Text, 4, 2), Left(TextBox1.Text, 2)) > Now() Then
        Reply = MsgBox("Das eingegebene Datum liegt in der Zukunft." & vbNewLine & "Wollen Sie es so lassen?", vbYesNo, "Datum in der Zukunft")
        If Reply = vbNo Then
            TextBox1.Text = Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY")
        End If
    End If
    If Mid(TextBox1.Text, 3, 1) <> "." Then TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 2) & "." & Right(TextBox1.Text, 7)
    If Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 1) <> "." Then TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 5) & "." & Right(TextBox1.Text, 4)
ElseIf Len(TextBox1.Text) > 10 Then
    TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 10)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```